# Android Java Library both ways compatible

Tags: java, android

I've made an API Wrapper with Android Studio, mainly to be used with Android Apps. I would like to make a .JAR file out of it, so that Java applications may also use it.

Is that possible? If so, how?

I've looked at how to make .JAR files out of Android Pojects, but not much came out of it. I also don't understand how is the Java application going to handle the Android net import, for example.

Comment: *I also don't understand how is the Java application going to handle the Android net import, for example.* ... with nice **NoClassDefFoundError**

Answer (score 1):

you can add a "jar" task to your lib-s `build.gradle` to generate a jar like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    ...
}

task jar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

You have to keep in mind that ordinary non-android java apps cannot use classes that directly or inderectly depend on namespaces `android.*`

---

I prefer to create an ordinary non android-dependant java-library-subproject in android-studio that generates a jar file and that can be consumed by your android-app.

One additional benefit of seperation non-android-lib from android-app is that you can write junit-4 tests for them.

Ordinary android-junit tests depend on junit3. Executing android-junit-tests requires to launch the emulator/android-device which is timeconsuming.

An ordinary non-android-junit-test runs much faster because it does not need emulator/android-device

Comment: I agree the lib should be non-android, but I am using android.net.Uri at the moment. How would I replace that in my non-android lib? How would Android later understand it? Would http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html work?

Comment: you cannot use `android.net.Uri` in a non android apps so you have to implement all uri operations using `String` + `java.net.URI` + `java.net.URLDecoder` + `java.net.URLEncoder` which are available in android, too. I have solved a similar issue by passing uri-strings around.

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty clear android imports would not work. Thanks for sharing your solution, though, that was what I was after :)